# Start a Hive query from Python and monitor its state progress

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, thrift

I am trying to start a long running (2-10 minutes) Hive query from Python in the background, then monitor its state and progress.

I managed to connect to Hive server using thrift and I run "ExecuteStatement" successfully with "runAsync" option, I also got the job ID from the log, but as soon as I end my Python program the job get killed!

Am I missing anything? or is the only way to keep the query/job running is to keep my thrift connection live?

The second part is monitoring the state and progress; If I got the job ID, would it be enough to access the Hive query state? or does Hive run multiple jobs for a signle query? one for each stage maybe?